# Setting environment variables with background processes running in parallel

Tags: bash, environment-variables, child-process

I have a file that takes 1 min to source. So within that file I need to source, I created functions and then ran them in parallel using &. The exported variables from the child processes are not available in the current environment. Is there a solution or trick to solve this issue? Thanks.
Sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
function getCNAME() {
 curl ...... grep
 export CNAME
} 

function getBNAME() {
  curl ...... grep
  export BNAME 
}
getCNAME &
getBNAME &
```

And then I have a main file that calls the source command on the code above and tries to use the variables BNAME and CNAME. But is unable to do so. If I remove the & it does have access to those variable but takes a long time to source the file.

Comment: Can you show what you're doing with a minimal example of the file to source and how you call it? I'm not sure I understand where exactly you call your functions.

Comment: `#!bin/bash
function getCNAME() {
  curl ...... grep 
  export CNAME
}

function getBNAME() {
  curl ...... grep 
  export BNAME
} 
CNAME &
BNAME &`

Comment: You should [edit] the question with that information, comments are harder to read and ephemeral.

Comment: A sub-shell cannot export or pass variables to its parent shell.

Comment: Why has the file a shebang, if you source it? A shebang is necessary to execute a script. But it is useless if you source your file. And it influences the environment. If you execute the script, any `export` definition has no effect on the calling process. And of course you have to wait for the background job. Just add `wait` at the end.

Comment: ...and because background jobs all run in subprocesses by nature, they have their own environment variables, separate from the parent's.

Comment: BTW, `function funcname() {` is an antipattern; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- it's mixing POSIX sh and ksh syntax in a way that isn't compatible with _either_ POSIX sh or legacy ksh, and that doesn't have the advantages that ksh implemented `function` to provide. Just use `funcname() {`, with no preceding `function`, for the widest possible compatibility.

Comment: The "solution" is to understand why it takes more than 500 ms to source the file and fix the problem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...well, in this case, that's because the files are making requests of a web service; I'm presuming that service is at fault.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `export` in your subshell and expect the parent shell to have access to the resulting variable. Consider using process substitutions instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
# note that if you're sourcing this, as you should be, the shebang will be ignored.
# ...hopefully it's just there for your editor's syntax highlighting.

rc=0
orig_pipefail_setting=$(shopt -p pipefail)
shopt -s pipefail # make sure if either curl _or_ grep fails the entire pipeline does too

# start both processes in the background, with their stdout on two different FDs
exec 4< <(curl ... | grep ... && printf '\0')
exec 5< <(curl ... | grep ... && printf '\0')

# read from those FDs into variables in the current shell
IFS= read -r -d '' BNAME <&4 || { (( rc |= $? )); echo "Error reading BNAME" >&2; }
IFS= read -r -d '' CNAME <&5 || { (( rc |= $? )); echo "Error reading CNAME" >&2; }

exec 4<&- 5<&-      # close those file descriptors now that we're done with them
export BNAME CNAME  # note that you probably don't actually need to export these
eval "$orig_pipefail_setting"  # turn pipefail back off, if it wasn't on when we started
return "$rc"        # ...return with an exit status reflecting whether we had any errors
```

That way file descriptors 4 and 5 will each be attached to a shell pipeline running `curl` and feeding its output to `grep`; both of them are started in the background before we try to read from either, so they're both running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the last two lines shouldn't be:

```
getCNAME
getBNAME
```

Edit - OP has fixed this, it used to read:

```
CNAME
BNAME
```

If you are sourcing a script (`. /my/script`), it is *not* a child process, and its variables *will* be available in the current shell. You don't even need export.

If you are executing a script normally, it *is* a child process, and you *can't* set variables in the parent shell.

The only methods I'm aware of of transferring data to the parent shell are via a file.

The variables should be available.
Check for bugs in your script:
Make sure you haven't used `local` for the variables in the functions.
Do `echo "$CNAME"` at the bottom of the sourced script, to test the functions are actually working at all.

EDIT

I did a little more investigation. Here is the problem: **`&` puts the command/function in a subshell**. That's why the variable is not available. In a *sourced* script, without `&`, it would be.

From `man bash`:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
> executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does
> not wait for the command to  finish, and the return status is 0.
> These are referred to as asynchronous commands.

Comment: The OP is trying to run both processes in parallel because they're slow. Not backgrounding them would fix the problem, but would defeat the intended performance improvement.